# Can jQuery css get inline styles also?

Tags: jquery, html, css

As far as I know `$(element).css()` can get linked stylesheet information specific to the element. Can `.css()`also get inline styles? If so, do I need to specify different parameter value? For example, if I need to get background color, should I call both `$(element).css('background-color')` and `$(element).css('backgroundColor')`?

Comment: I know this is a question and answer site... but why don't you just test it and find out? It is 1 line of code...

Comment: You can just try it, it's one line of code

Comment: Indeed, Would have cost you less time and work to try it out than to formulate this question.

Comment: The question should be rewritten as "Do jQuery css get something except inline styles"

Comment: If you know the answer, why don't you answer the question rather than just chit chatting? Indeed, Would have cost you less time if any of you had answered it already.

Comment: Because we don't appreciate being taken advantage of by help vampires. Show some effort before posting a question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As people have said in the comments, this question is something that you might have easily found out for yourself. Since we're here anyway though, here's the answer:
The .css() function can read both inline styles and separate styles (via link or style tags), but when it does write styles (when it has a parameter), it only modifies the inline style of the element.

You can find more about this [here](http://api.jquery.com/css/)

Answer (score 0):

```
var colorspan = document.createElement("span");
      colorspan.setAttribute('style','width:25px; height:25px');
      colorspan.setAttribute('id','promotcolor');
      var pormot = document.getElementById("promotcolor");
      pormot.style.backgroundColor = color;
```

Comment: Code dumps without any explanation are rarely helpful. Stack Overflow is about learning, not providing snippets to blindly copy and paste. Please [edit] your question and explain how it works better than what the OP provided. See [answer].